# Why does this bulk insert not work as expected?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-5

Please see this code snippet:

```
while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    ....
    Departamento depto = db.Departamento.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DepNombre.Equals(departamento, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (depto == null)
    {
        depto = new Departamento();
        depto.DepNombre = departamento;
        depto.Pais = pais;
        depto.DepCreadoEn = DateTime.Now;
        db.Departamento.Add(depto);
    }
    ...
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

As you see, I have a loop that is inserting data into table `Departamento` in the database. For instance, this is importing records from an Excel sheet.

That "if" is there to insert records that is not in the database, according to its name (`DepNombre`). When that name exists, get the current object, so that, it does not appear twice in the database table.

As you also see, I am calling `SaveChanges()` after the loop, for performance reasons.

The curious thing is that the object is not currently added to the collection, so, "depto" object always returns null, adding the record several times.

For example, there is currently 1 record in the database. By using immediate window, I can call `db.Departamento.Count()` and 1 record is found. After the `db.Departamento.Add` call, I call the same `Count()` method and 1 is returned again. In that case, obviously the `FirstOrDefault` method will never return anything.

`SaveChanges` call actually populates the tables with the imported records.

Any help, please?

Comment: So, do you understand why it doesn't work, and you're just looking for someone to fix it for you?  Or you are looking for an explanation as to why it;s not working in the first place?

Comment: I need to solve the error... for that reason, I need to know why it is not working.... I think if I add the object to the collection, it should be considered in the next interation, so, the FirstOrDefault call will return it.

Comment: Doing an add only adds the entity in memory.  Nothing gets pushed to the database until you do SaveChanges().  Because you do SaveChanges() at the very end (after the loop completes), your query in the loop always returns null, because it really isn't there, in the database, yet.

Comment: So the FirstOrDefault method tries to query the database instead of the collection in memory, doesn't it? what solution may I implement so that it does not impact performance? by doing a COMMIT for each record, it will be very slow.

Comment: Read the excel records into a `List<Departamento>`.  Group the records by DepNombre.  Then Iterate and insert.  If you want to get fancy, you can skip the iterate and insert and do a bulk exclude, and then bulk insert via .AddRange()

Comment: Apart from Robert McKee's suggestion, if your only real concern is the performance penalty of doing a commit on every iteration, you can also consider wrapping your whole operation in a transaction.  By doing that, you can move the SaveChanges() back inside the loop. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843) for more info on how to do that.

Comment: Each iteration goes through employees. For each employee, the corresponding department is added or retrieved if it was already added. You are suggesting to add departments first and COMMIT and then employees. Well... since I wrote only a snippet, I tell you that I will need to add more loops, because in this way, I am adding Companies, and Business areas, Also, the employee can be repeated in the Excel file, so I will need to add employees to a List<> collection too, and then add all records to DB context.

Comment: I am wondering if this changed in EntiryFramework versions, because I have developed this application on 2013 and at that time, this loop worked, and even, I used this way to import employees. I have updated entity framework and I don't know why this stoped working.

Comment: If departmento table's primary key is depNombre, you can use .Find instead, which will look in the memory to be commited.

Comment: It is not primary key

Comment: The answers will always depend on how big your dataset is.  If you build up the correct objects in memory first, then it is fairly easy to run through each level of the object graph to insert only new items.  You will also only be doing 1 SQL select per graph level (instead of one for each object at each level).  It will be significantly faster.  If that extra speed isn't important, then there are easier ways.

Comment: Essentially, if you have BusinessAreas that contains companies that contains departments that contains employees, and you are just inserting new, but not updating existing, then you just repeat what I have for an answer from the group by through add to database steps 4 times, flattening the object model with SelectMany as you go.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list=new List<Departamento>();
/* Get from Excel */
while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    ....
    depto = new Departamento();
    depto.DepNombre = departamento;
    depto.Pais = pais;
    depto.DepCreadoEn = DateTime.Now;
    list.Add(depto);
}

/* Group By */
var list2=list.GroupBy(x=>x.DepNombre,(key,g)=>g.OrderBy(e=>e.DepCreadoEn).First());

/* Get list of DepNombre to exclude */
var badDepts=db.Departmento
  .Where(d=>list2.Any(l2=>l2.DepNombre==d.DepNombre))
  .Select(d=>d.DepNombre);

/* Exclude them */
var goodDepts=list2.Where(l=>!badDepts.Any(bd=>bd==l.DepNombre));

/* Add to database */
db.Departmento.AddRange(goodDepts);

/* Save */
db.SaveChanges();
```